# Auto complete base on value of dropdown in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, autocomplete

I'm stuck with this problem with in a week. What I have here is dropdown select with ajax posting value to another dropdown but now I need to post into textbox with autocomplete function. What I need is connect my autocomplete query and my ajax so that if I select for example ballpen, all ballpen will recommend in autocomplete. Please Help me with this. I need to finish it.

Here's my code

**Ajax.php**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#tag").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
        selectFirst: true
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<br/>
 Drop1
 <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015");
    $combo = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM category GROUP BY cat_code ORDER BY id");
    $option = '';
     while($row = $combo->fetch_assoc())
        {
        $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['cat_code'].'">'.$row['category'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>

<select id="main" name="main">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
Auto Complete <input id="tag">
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#main').change(function(){
$.ajax({
url : 'getajax.php',
data :{mainlist_id : $(this).val()},
dataType:'html',
type:'POST',
success:function(data){
$('#tag').html(data);
}
});
});
</script>
```

getajax.php

In here I post the value in another dropdown but not I need to post into textbox.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["mainlist_id"])) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015");
    $main = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["mainlist_id"]);


$result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM code WHERE cat_code='$main' GROUP BY item_code ORDER BY item");

    while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc())
    {
    ?>
    <option value ="<?php echo $row['item_code'];?>"><?php echo $row['item'];?></option>';
<?php
    }
    }
?>
```

autocomplete.php

```
<?php
    //$q=$_GET['q'];
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015") or die("Database Error");
    $auto = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["q"]);
    //$main = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["mainlist_id"]); AND cat_code='$main'
    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM code WHERE item LIKE '%$auto%' GROUP BY id ORDER BY item" ); 

    if($sql)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            echo $row['item']."\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: @Lupin when I run the code and try to input in #tag field nothings appears

Comment: Did you debug it? try alerting or using console.log for data variable upon AJAX success

Answer (score 0):

//whenever u select the tag field will get focus, and it automatically start searching so u no need to type see the callback focus function with $(this).autocomplete("search", ""); and minlength 0. u have to send the main value and get the response from here too

```
<script>
$(document).on("keyup", "#tag", function(){
    $("#tag").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON("autocomplete_gethere.php", { main: $("#main").val() }, response);
        },
        minLength:0
        }).focus(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
    });
});
</script> 

     <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#main').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url : 'getajax.php',
        data :{mainlist_id : $(this).val()},
        dataType:'html',
        type:'POST',
        success:function(data){
        $('#tag').focus();    //please note this, here we're focusing in that input field
        }
        });
        });
        </script>
```

untested, if any question post comment

Comment: doesn't work. What the use of $(this).autocomplete("search", "");

Comment: it start displaying results before you start typing

Comment: just like what you said. How to fix this?